# Custom template for PasswordResetConfirmView

Tags: django

I am wanting to create a template for a user to enter new password and confirm password after opening the password reset link. Currently it is leading to a page with title django administration.
This is my urls.py:

```
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

I am wanting to know what name should I use for the input fields of new password and confirm password. I searched through the internet and found out many people were using django forms which I am not doing so I wasnt able to find what the name attribute should have in input tag for passwordresetconfirmview.

Comment: `auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='name_of_template.html')`.

Comment: Yes I know that but this is not the problem. The problem is that what should i put in the name attribute of input tag of new password and confirm password so that it is fetched by the view

Comment: It uses a [**`SetPasswordForm`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4376c2c7f8cd9c7604a7d053b3c4022dd5ac2795/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L329) so `new_password1` and `new_password2`.

Comment: That being said, styling a form can be done with the form itself. You can for example make use of crispy-forms, or other extensions that render the form differently. By using a custom HTML, you make it less "robust" against future changes. This is one of the reasons Django has forms, to make it easy to alter forms based on changes in the models, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`PasswordResetConfirmView`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L247-L317) is a class-based view that specifies a `form_class`:

> ```
> class PasswordResetConfirmView(PasswordContextMixin,
> FormView):
>     form_class = SetPasswordForm
>     # …
> ```

This [**`SetPasswordForm`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L329-L370) uses two fields:

> ```
> class SetPasswordForm(forms.Form):
>     # …
>     new_password1 = forms.CharField(
>         label=_("New password"),
>         widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'new-password'}),
>         strip=False,
>         help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
>     )
>     new_password2 = forms.CharField(
>         label=_("New password confirmation"),
>         strip=False,
>         widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'new-password'}),
>     )
>     # …
> ```

So you can specify a `template_name`:

```
path(
    'reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
    auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        template_name='some_template_name.html'
    ),
    name='password_reset_confirm'
),
```

and in the template uses `new_password1` and `new_password2` as form elements.

That being said, often it is better *not* to manually construct a HTML form, but use tooling, like for example [**`django-crispy-forms`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms) to render the form differently. This is more robust. For example if in future versions of Django, the form changes, the rendering engine will still render a correct HTML form. It also avoids a lot of *boilerplate code*.