# Customize PasswordResetConfirmView

Tags: django

I'm trying to set a user is_active state to True when the user have clicked on the reset-password link I've emailed them. However, I don't understand how to get access to the PasswordResetConfirmView, the code below don't do any prints when I go to the related URL.

Any ideas on how I should do this?

I've read the source code over here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/views.py

But I don't really understand how I should "intercept" the view and add the operations I want to do and then let it keep going.

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

     
   class PasswordResetConfirmView(auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView):
              
        print("Request view")
        
        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            print(request)
            print(request.user)
            return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is the related URL

```
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="main/password/password_reset_confirm.html"), name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

**EDIT**:
Also tried adjusting the loginview, but got the same problem. I think I'm mistunderstand how things work behind the hood.

```
class LoginUser(auth_views.LoginView):
print("test")
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print("test")
    return super(LoginUser, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get_success_url(self):
    return resolve_url('accounts:login')
```

Comment: Your print should be in a contructor to be executed.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how that would look like?

Comment: I'm not even sure if the fact that the `PasswordResetConfirmView` has the same name of your class is causing a breaking in the importing. You could try to rename it to see if that's the case.

Comment: I tried this, but still not working: class New_PasswordResetConfirmView(auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Testing")
        super(New_PasswordResetConfirmView,self)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63489958/16299715

Answer (score 1):

You can override the [**`SetPasswordForm`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.SetPasswordForm), and activate the user object:

```python
from django.contrib.auth.forms import SetPasswordForm

class MySetPasswordForm(SetPasswordForm):
    
    def save(self, *args, commit=True, **kwargs):
        user = super().save(*args, commit=False, **kwargs)
        user.is_active = True
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Then we can use this as our `MySetPasswordForm`:

```
path(
    'reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
    views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(form_class=MySetPasswordForm),
    name='password_reset_confirm'
),
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to implement it. But testing the user after password has been resetted for is_active in the shell still show False. However, I can login the user now, and couldn't do it before.. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jhnsbrst: what user model do you use?

Comment: See my custom usermanager and usermodel: https://gist.github.com/minifisk/bd0596d62b1aad407c5022c996e8bf7f here is the full repo: https://github.com/minifisk/jobsbackend/tree/master/jobs/jobs_backend

Comment: @Jhnsbrst: what does `print(user)` do after the `user = super()...` call?

Comment: Furthermore in the related path, you should set the `form_class` with:
`auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="main/password/password_reset_confirm.html", form_class=MySetPasswordForm)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234400/discussion-between-jhnsbrst-and-willem-van-onsem).